# Select Data from two tables ONLY IF ID on both tables are SAME

Tags: mysql, select, exists

I need to select returns result

```
SELECT wl.id FROM wishlist AS wl
LEFT JOIN wishlist_products AS wp ON wl.id = wp.wishlist_id
```

Only IF ALL of wp.product_id EXISTS in wishlist_products_bought.product_id

Thanks

Comment: Change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`??  Or am I missing something in the question?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Could you try them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT wl.id 
FROM wishlist AS wl
LEFT JOIN wishlist_products AS wp ON wl.id = wp.wishlist_id
WHERE  wp.product_id in (select product_id from wishlist_products_bought)
```

Comment: The additional condition must be in the ON clause, because otherwice you will convert LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: It does not satisfy condition Only IF ALL of wp.product_id EXISTS in wishlist_products_bought.product_id

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume these are your table definitions (simplified to the minimum):

```
CREATE TABLE wishlist
(
    wishlist_id integer PRIMARY KEY
) ;

CREATE TABLE products
(
    product_id integer PRIMARY KEY
) ;

CREATE TABLE wishlist_products
(
    wishlist_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES wishlist(wishlist_id),
    product_id integer NOT NULL  REFERENCES products(product_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (wishlist_id, product_id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE wishlist_products_bought
(
    wishlist_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES wishlist(wishlist_id),
    product_id integer NOT NULL  REFERENCES products(product_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (wishlist_id, product_id)
) ;
```

And these are your data: 3 products, 2 wishlists. One of the wishlists (1) has all the products "bought", the other one doesn't (2).

```
INSERT INTO wishlist
VALUES (1), (2) ;

INSERT INTO products
VALUES (10), (20), (30) ;

INSERT INTO wishlist_products
VALUES (1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 10), (2, 20), (2, 30) ;

INSERT INTO wishlist_products_bought
VALUES (1, 10), (1, 20), (2, 20) ;
```

If I understand your objective: you're trying to identify the wishlist with all the products already "bought". That can be done with some `set` logic. Basically, you want to make sure that the set of all *products* from the wishlist is completely contained in the list of *products bought* (for the same wishlist). To check for full containment, you can do A - B = (empty set). This can be accomplished in SQL by using the `EXCEPT`. So, this query would do it:

```
SELECT
     wishlist_id
FROM
     wishlist w
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS
     ( SELECT product_id FROM wishlist_products wp        
        WHERE wp.wishlist_id = w.wishlist_id
       EXCEPT
       SELECT product_id FROM wishlist_products_bought wb 
        WHERE wb.wishlist_id = w.wishlist_id
     ) ;
```

You can check it at http://rextester.com/YOUE97199  (using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL).

There's one problem: *this doesn't work with MySQL*, because MySQL doesn't understand `EXCEPT` (nor any equivalent); and doesn't understand `wishlist_id` within the `WHERE` in the subquery. Which means an equivalent using `NOT EXISTS` cannot be used.

To overcome these limitations, we can use two functions [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), and use the following (more complicated that I like) query:

```
SELECT
    wishlist_id, product_id_list
FROM
(
    SELECT
        w.wishlist_id,
        (SELECT
             GROUP_CONCAT(wb.product_id SEPARATOR ',')
         FROM
             wishlist_products_bought wb
         WHERE
             wb.wishlist_id = w.wishlist_id
         ORDER BY
             product_id
         ) AS product_id_list
    FROM
        wishlist w
) AS q1 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 
            product_id 
        FROM 
            wishlist_products wp
        WHERE 
            wp.wishlist_id = q1.wishlist_id
            AND FIND_IN_SET(product_id, product_id_list) = 0
    ) ;
```

You can also check it at http://rextester.com/OLKK85405